# JSP Conditional to check HTML Element classes

Tags: html, class, jsp, jstl, conditional-statements

I am writing a conditional choose in JSP that will change the URL of a link, but I want it to check the assigned class of the body.

```
<c:choose>
     <c:when test="${body.class == 'this'}">
         //Do This
     </c:when>
     <c:otherwise>
          //Do That
     </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>

<html>
<body class="that">
</body>
</html>
```

Is this even possible? Is the syntax of test="${body.class = 'this'}" proper?

Comment: Ok, so what's your problem on achieving it with your above code?

Comment: @Sas - edited original question to address the unclarity

Comment: @Sas, I'm asking if this is the correct syntax, I apologize for any confusion.  I'm not fully well-versed in JSP yet

Comment: You are mixing up server side code with client side code. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

JSTL is server side code & your body is html, client side. Use jQuery/ Javascript to achive this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var css=$("body").attr("class"); 
   if(css == "this"){
      // do this 
   }else{
      // do that
   }
});
```

Comment: I have alternative methods of achiveing what I am after, I just wanted to know if server-side code can check html? I assume that it cannot.

Comment: Yes you can't. If you want you can work around it by specifying the class name in request scope and substituting it in jsp. Then you can check if/else condition using JSTL. i.e. <body class="${class}">